# Word for temporary obsession

Tags: single-word-requests

Me and a friend were discussing something we experience (too) often: we discover some new concept or thing (for example "photography" or "knitting", can be anything) and become completely obsessed with that thing for a short period of time. Most often though this temporary obsession disappears as sudden as it appeared.

Is there a word for this all too common state of sudden, temporary obsession?

Comment: *(passing) fad* -- see **fad**: "A fashion that is taken up with great enthusiasm for a brief period of time; a craze;" "a personal idiosyncrasy or whim" TFD http://www.thefreedictionary.com/FAD

Answer (score 3):

How about a [flare](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flare)?

```
a sudden burst, as of zeal or of anger
```

http://dictionary.reference.com/

Answer (score 2):

A  [passing fancy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/fancy):

> - A passing fashion, activity, or feeling lasts for only a short period of time and is not worth taking very seriously.

(Cambridge Dict.)

Answer (score 2):

- a word for "temporary obsession" is "infatuation".

> Vocabulary.com puts it as:
>
> **[Infatuation](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/infatuation)** is falling in love with or becoming extremely interested *in someone or something* **for a short time.**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it just your *latest craze*

> Latest craze n.
>
> 1:  an exaggerated and often transient enthusiasm :  mania 'the latest craze in music'

**Reference**: 'Latest craze' n. Merriam-Webster Dictionary online. Accessed 03/03/2015