# Noun for something you dabble in

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word (or maybe two) for an interest or hobby that you dabble in briefly, especially in the context of dabbling in many of these interests over time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word for the object of a dilettante?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/555957/is-there-a-word-for-the-object-of-a-dilettante)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - are you sure this is a duplicate of that question ??????

Comment: @669 Yes. 'A dilettante is currently defined as:

"a person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge" - OED, online (2020) version': one who dabbles in an interest (and 'without real commitment' usually refers to a time limit). The duplicate uses 'object' to refer to the area of interest: 'my ___ include astronomy and metaphysics'. // You could add the answer 'fad' at the earlier question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - not sure the OP has a dilettante in mind, but probably someone who is just  temporarily attracted by new interests, who are not necessarily dilettanti.

Comment: Why don't you think "hobby" or "interest" applies? What research have you done, e.g. thesaurus? Is there any type of thing you're particularly interested in? It helps to provide more information.

Comment: There are many similar questions on ELU. [...A word ... someone who dives into something ... and then moves on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409510/im-looking-for-a-word-thats-like-a-whimsical-fanatic-someone-who-dives-in-to-s/409529#409529) // [a word or a term used for someone who hops from idea to idea ... without ever really completing any of them.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138853/someone-who-hops-from-idea-to-idea) /[Word for temporary obsession](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231454/word-for-temporary-obsession/231457#231457) (passing fancy)

Comment: Reminder: A thesaurus to find related words, followed if necessary by a dictionary to check which word best expresses your idea, is the classic way to resolve such questions. And free thesauri and dictionaries are available on the network, including some which combine the two functions to make this easier. Asking the group mind should usually be a last resort if that fails or would have some subtle shading those don't resolve.

Comment: "Any English noun can be verbed", and in some dialect probably is frequently verbed. That doesn't mean it's the best word, though, especially when communicating with people outside that dialect. "A dabble" would strike me as quirky phrasing but understandable with some effort, just as the Indian English "a doubt" to mean a question does.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141068/discussion-on-question-by-hashim-aziz-noun-for-something-you-dabble-in).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In three words, this could be called *a passing fancy*:

> **a passing fancy**
>
> Something that captures one's interest or enthusiasm for only a brief
> period of time.
>
> <sub>*Jim was really into learning about horticulture for a while, but
> it turned out to be only a passing fancy.*</sub>
>
> <sub>*I played a few sports during college, but they were all just
> passing fancies.*</sub>
>
> <sub>*She sure spent a lot of money on that fancy camera, so I really
> hope photography isn't just a passing fancy for her.*</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [The Free
> Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+passing+fancy)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I immediately upvoted your answer lol. Perfect match for the question, in my opinion.

Comment: This is something one dabble***d*** in, not something one dabble***s*** in. So like, don't even ask me to do it because I don't anymore. As opposed to, don't ask me to do it because I suck at it.

Comment: @Mazura — *Photography is just a passing fancy for her* means she is doing it now, dabbling in it now.

Comment: So says you, unless you are clairvoyant. *It's just a phase* huh? *Hopefully*  photography is just a passing fancy for her because she sucks at it or because I don't like her work. ... "for only a brief period of time" not, *only for brief period**s** of time*.

Comment: "turned out to be" - "but they were" - "I really *hope*" - all of the examples are past tense or projections about the future that hope to make it past tense as soon as possible.

Answer (score 8):

Historically, an avocation was exactly this, but it has gained a more formal tone and today implies a more serious level of devotion and usually concerns a respectable subject matter.

Today, I'd just call it a pastime.

Answer (score 6):

How about a **dalliance**:

> brief or casual involvement with something
>
> "Berkeley was my last dalliance with the education system."
>
> Source: Oxford Languages

Dalliance is most commonly used in a romantic sense, but it can also be used in other contexts to suggest similarities to a passing fling.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a "hobby" or a "venture" if looking for a noun.

Example:   "Yes, I have **ventured** into the world of corporate finance when I have extra time."

Comment: But beware implying a "business venture," which ought involve more than dabbling.

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[fad](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fad?q=fad)*** may suits your request:

> an intense and widely shared enthusiasm for something, especially one that is short-lived.

(OLD)

Comment: Fad often suggests something that a lot of people are interested in (some definitions emphasise it as something that's [very popular](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fad) for a brief period), like a craze or fashion, but I don't think that's an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 1):

How about **avocation**?

Definition from Oxford Languages: "a hobby or minor occupation"